# Array's first element won't output with no of char limit

Tags: c++, visual-studio

The program assignment requires a user to input words and then output the 'first' and 'last' element (lexical order). However, once the user inputs a four-letter word, the program must stop.

I still can't figure it out. :( Any help one can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the example output:
[image: Output]

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string arrayString[20];
    int counter = 0, N = sizeof(arrayString) / sizeof(arrayString[0]);

    cout << "String of words with lexical order and char limit" << endl;
    cout << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        cout << "Enter string: " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> arrayString[i];

        if (arrayString[i].length() == 4) {
            break;
            counter++;
        }
    }

    sort(arrayString, arrayString + N);
    cout << "\nFirst: " << arrayString[0] << endl;
    cout << "Last: " << arrayString[N - 1] << endl;

    if (counter == 1) {
        cout << "\nInvalid! You entered a four-letter word" << endl;
    }

    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why read the words into an array?  You just need `std::string`s for the first and last (lexographically) values seen so far, which you can update as you see each new string.

Comment: `N` has a value of 20, so `sort(arrayString, arrayString + N);` sorts 20 string. But you have only entered 4 strings.

Comment: This is the same problem as finding the minimum and maximum numbers, but with strings - you don't need to store all the inputs and you don't need to sort. (The purpose of the exercise is very likely that you should notice this.)

Answer (score 3):

`N` has a value of 20, so `sort(arrayString, arrayString + N);` sorts 20 strings. But you have only entered 4 strings.

You need to use `counter` not `N`.

So you need to fix your code so `counter` is calculated correctly, like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    cout << "Enter string: " << i + 1 << ": ";
    cin >> arrayString[i];

    if (arrayString[i].length() == 4) {
        break;
    }
    counter++;
}
```

Then use `counter` instead of `N` when you sort and print the results.

```
sort(arrayString, arrayString + counter);
cout << "\nFirst: " << arrayString[0] << endl;
cout << "Last: " << arrayString[counter - 1] << endl;
```

Comment: *"You need to use counter not N."* - it's `i` that matters (which will need to be moved to function scope), not `counter` (which needs to be incremented before the `break` to even fulfil its ostensibly intended use of indicating whether a four-letter word was encountered).

Comment: @TonyDelroy I didn't initially notice the problem with `counter`. That's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do away with `N = sizeof(arrayString) / sizeof(arrayString[0]);`.

Also,

```
    if (counter == 1) {
        cout << "\nInvalid! You entered a four-letter word" << endl;
    }
```

is not needed. You can include this withing your `for()` loop. This way, your `counter` variable itself can be used to find last index, or to know how many items you have in your list.

Maybe this could work :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string arrayString[20];
    int counter = 0;

    cout << "String of words with lexical order and char limit" << endl;
    cout << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        cout << "Enter string: " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> arrayString[i];
        if (arrayString[i].length() == 4) {
            counter++;
            cout<<"\nInvalid! You entered a four-letter word" << endl;
            break;
        }
        counter++;
    }

    sort(arrayString, arrayString + counter); 
    cout << "\nFirst: " << arrayString[0] << endl;
    cout << "Last: " << arrayString[counter - 1] << endl;

    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You overcomplicated the problem. You don't need to store all strings and sort them. You can compare the input with the current min and max value and replace it if necessary.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string arrayString[2];
    int counter = 0;

    cout << "String of words with lexical order and char limit" << endl;
    cout << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        cout << "Enter string: " << i + 1 << ": ";
        std::string input;
        cin >> input;

        if (i == 0) {
            arrayString[0] = input;
            arrayString[1] = input;
        } else {
            arrayString[0] = std::min(input, arrayString[0]);
            arrayString[1] = std::max(input, arrayString[0]);
        }

        if (input.length() == 4) {
            counter = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << "\nFirst: " << arrayString[0] << endl;
    cout << "Last: " << arrayString[1] << endl;

    if (counter == 1) {
        cout << "\nInvalid! You entered a four-letter word" << endl;
    }

    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have filled less than `N` strings in your array when you sort them the first string is empty.

The fix is to update `N` with the number of strings entered:

```
if (arrayString[i].length() == 4) {
  N = i + 1;
  counter++;
  break;
}
```

Note `counter++` is moved before the `break` otherwise it won't execute.

This would be simpler with `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> arrayString;
    int counter = 0;

    std::cout << "String of words with lexical order and char limit\n";
    std::cout << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        std::cout << "Enter string: " << i + 1 << ": ";
        std::string str;
        std::cin >> str;
        arrayString.push_back(str);

        if (str.length() == 4) {
            counter++;
            break;
        }
    }

    std::sort(arrayString.begin(), arrayString.end());
    std::cout << "\nFirst: " << arrayString.front() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Last: " << arrayString.back() << "\n";

    if (counter == 1) {
        std::cout << "\nInvalid! You entered a four-letter word\n";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```